# Grid is not zeroed in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

I have a document with several artboards (7), which I resized, but now my grid (cmd–") is not centered or zeroed correctly (please see photo). I need to adjust the elements on the artboards, and I need the grid to zeroed correctly, otherwise there's no point in using it. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

[image: grid]

Answer (score 22):

Your document is set to display 'Global rulers', and one ruler applies to the document. While using global rulers you can double-click the origin point to reset the global ruler to the top-left of the selected artboard.

[image: Origin rulers]

From the menu choose `View > Rulers > Change to Artboard Rulers` (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to switch to Artboard rulers which will allow you to reset the coordinates for each artboard.

Comment: Ah, clicking the artboard tool and then double-clicking the origin point on the rulers works—THANK YOU!!

Comment: @R.Fischer Don't forget to select this as your answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you've been doing some resizing, and you're building for web, also check that your artboards are on the pixel grid. Switch to the Artboards tool: The dimensions and absolute position will appear in the control bar.

The document grid will follow your ruler origin (per artboard, as Skaught mentioned) but the pixel grid is essentially fixed across the doc and can really cause you some headaches. I'm hoping someone can tell me this problem is gone in CS6, though I'm not sure how they'd fix it in practice.